# MvvmCross RaisePropertyChanged and dot (.) binding

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a custom binding that accepts entire view model:

```
public class TextViewGroupInfoBinding : BaseBinding<TextView, GroupViewModel>
{
    private IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity CurrentTopActivity
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>(); }
    }
    public TextViewGroupInfoBinding(TextView androidControl) : base(androidControl)
    {
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
    }

    protected override void SetValueToView(TextView control, GroupViewModel value)
```

And on UI to bind it the `MvxBind="BgColor ."` Syntax is used. How can I rase `PropertyChanged` event from my `ViewModel` for the binding to react? Tried `RaiseAllPropertiesChanged` with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a "Self" property to your ViewModel or View, which returns itself. Then just bind to that Property instead of dot (.) syntax:

```
public MyViewModel Self
{
    get { return this; }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This was such an elegant solution. Thank you.